# How to render the 'actions' section of a form in twig template?

Tags: forms, 8, theming

given a form that is built like the following:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
{
   $form['#theme'] = 'mymodule_testForm';
   $form['actions']['#type'] = 'actions';
   $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('submit'),
      '#button_type' => 'primary',
   );
   return $form;
}
```

How do I access the submit button in my twig template?

Comment: `{{ form.actions.submit }}` (assuming `'render element' => 'form'` in `hook_theme()`)?

Comment: But don't count to being able to alter anything in Twig. It's too late for that. If the variable in twig is not preprocessed, like attributes, you won't be able to do anything. I have created an issue for this in do.org already but I doubt anything will be done in 8.x branch. So back to good old hook_preprocess_hook.

Answer (score 1):

Hat tip to Clive who already answered the question as a comment:

```
{{ form.actions}}
```

To render the rest of the form, you can do something like `{{ form | without('actions') }}`

So you whole code will look something like this:

In my_module.module:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function my_module_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $result = [
    'custom_form' => [
      'render element' => 'form',
      'template' => 'custom-form',
    ],
  ];

  return $result;
}
```

And in custom-form.html.twig:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <h3>Form</h3>
    {{ form | without('actions') }}
</div>
<aside class="col-md-4">
    <h3>Action</h3>
    {{ form.actions }}
</aside>
```

For more reading:

- Similar Q&A:

  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48997506/how-to-render-specific-form-elements-drupal-8
  - [How to pass a custom Form to a Twig template](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/250914/how-to-pass-a-custom-form-to-a-twig-template)
- Drupal.org documentation on Twig filters in Drupal: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/filters-modifying-variables-in-twig-templates

Hope that helps!