# How to pass a custom Form to a Twig template

Tags: theming, 8, forms

my problem is that my drupal 8 form is not getting rendered in twig template.

I created a form with build form method in drupal 8 when i tried it to pass in twig template it is not getting passed.for example my code is

modulenameconfig.php

```
class modulenameConfigForm extends ConfigFormBase {

  /**

   * {@inheritdoc}

   */

  public function getFormId() {

    return 'modulename';

  } 
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form = parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
    $config = $this->config('modulename.settings');


    $form['first_name'] = array(

      '#type' => 'textfield',

      '#title' => $this->t('First Name'),

      '#default_value' => $config->get('modulename.first_name'),

      '#required' => TRUE,

    );


    $form['last_name'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Last Name'),
      '#default_value' => $config->get('modulename.last_name'),
      '#required' => TRUE,
    );
    return $form;

  }
 protected function getEditableConfigNames() {

    return [

      'modulename.settings',

    ];

  }
}
```

modulename.module

```
<?php


namespace Drupal\modulename\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\ConfigFormBase;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
/**
* Implements hook_menu()
*/



function modulename_theme() {
  return array(
    'modulename_form' => array(
      'render element' => 'form',
      'template' => 'modulename-form',
      'base hook' => 'form'
    ),
  );
}
```

my twig file in templates folder

modluename-form.html.twig

```
{%
  set body_classes = [
    logged_in ? 'user-logged-in',
    not root_path ? 'path-frontpage' : 'path-' ~ root_path|clean_class,
    node_type ? 'page-node-type-' ~ node_type|clean_class,
    db_offline ? 'db-offline',
  ]
%}                           


                           <h2>Personal Information</h2>    
                                    <form method="post">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="name">First Name</label>
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                              {{form.first_name}}

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="name">Last Name</label>

                                            <div class="input-group">

                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" required>

                                                <span class="input-group-addon danger"><span class="glyphicon icon-remove"></span></span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

any help will be greatly appriciated  help asap

Answer (score 3):

This structure will not work with the autoloader right now - your namespaces and directory structure needs to follow [these PSR-4 standards](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/psr-4-namespaces-and-autoloading-in-drupal-8). (In particular, setting a namespace in your `.module` will cause Drupal to not find your hooks, which must be in the global namespace.)

I'm not sure I understand your use case fully, but it sounds like you want to:

1. Create a form.
2. Create a route that serves this form.
3. Render the form with a custom template.

For the first, your form class should be something like this (and must be saved in a file matching the class name under `modulename/src/Form/{ClassName}.php`):

```
namespace Drupal\modulename\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\ConfigFormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class MyModuleConfigForm extends ConfigFormBase {

  public function getFormId() {
    return 'modulename_settings';
  }

  public function getEditableConfigNames() {
    return ['modulename.settings'];
  }

  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $formState) {
    // build the form
    $form['...'] = [
      //...
    ]; 

    parent::buildForm();
    return $form;
  }

  public function submitForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $formState) {
    $this->config('modulename.settings')
      // set the values from the form
      ->set('...', $formState->getValue('...'))
      ->save();

    parent::submitForm($form, $formState);
  }

}
```

For the second part, you need a `modulename.routing.yml` file that looks something like this:

```
modulename.settings:
  path: '/admin/config/mymodule'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\modulename\Form\MyModuleConfigForm'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer site configuration'
```

(This is for admin configuration forms, since you mentioned `ConfigFormBase`. If you want a more general form and open it to anonymous users, extend `FormBase` instead and put `_access: 'TRUE'` in the route requirements.)

Finally, for the third part, you need to create your theme hook in `modulename_theme()`. (Your code already works, although the `template` key is superfluous as it matches the default.)

Then, modify the `buildForm()` as follows:

```
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $formState) {
    // build the form
    $form['...'] = [
      //...
    ]; 

    parent::buildForm();

    // *After* parent call.
    $form['#theme'] = 'modulename_form';

    return $form;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Christoph . for helping me .

but unfortunately  your method is  also not  working. you mentioned modulename.theme.
but in drupal8 module development modulename.module file implements the hook_theme() method. please check again my code.

Comment: Hi, I am afraid there is a misunderstanding; I did not specify any modulename.theme file (which is not needed here, as there is no preprocessing). Most hooks including modulename_theme() must be defined in modulename.module, or they will not be found.

Comment: hi Christoph . now  my twig file is being called . but my custom css is not being applied . and please tell me how do we use bootstrap in drupal 8 module i.e how add it in modulename.libraries.yml file . and what is the use of form alter in this form.